# How to access microphone in Xamarin emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is it possible or is there anyway that I can access the Microphone and use it to test my code?

I have enabled all of this in the extended controls of my emulator for microphone:
[image]

I also have these permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Plugin.AudioRecorder;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AudioDemo
{

    [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        AudioRecorderService recorder;
        AudioPlayer player;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            recorder = new AudioRecorderService
            {
                StopRecordingAfterTimeout = true,
                TotalAudioTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                AudioSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
            };

            player = new AudioPlayer();
            player.FinishedPlaying += Finaliza_Reproducao;
        }

        async void Record_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!recorder.IsRecording) 
                {
                    recorder.StopRecordingOnSilence = TimeoutSwitch.IsToggled;

                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;
                    PlayButton.IsEnabled = false;

                    //Start recording
                    var audioRecordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();

                    RecordButton.Text = "Parar Gravação";
                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;

                    await audioRecordTask;

                    RecordButton.Text = "Record";
                    PlayButton.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;

                    //stop recording ...
                    await recorder.StopRecording();

                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //blow up the app!
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        async void Play_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var filePath = recorder.GetAudioFilePath();

                if (filePath != null)
                {
                    PlayButton.IsEnabled = false;
                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;

                    player.Play(filePath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //blow up the app!
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        void Finaliza_Reproducao(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlayButton.IsEnabled = true;
            RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works when I use a phone to run it, but when I just use (my laptop) emulator, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not able to record sound in the emulator because the android emulator doesn’t support it yet. This code should only work on the phone.

> Note: The Android Emulator cannot record audio. Be sure to test your
>   code on a real device that can record.

This is the official document

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder?hl=en

Comment: Oh, Thank you for this. I only have limited access to a phone that's why I want to use the emulator to test my code